# Linq group by date range

Tags: c#, linq

I have collection that I need to group if the parent key is common AND if the date field is within n (e.g. 2) hours of each other.

Sample data:

```
List<DummyObj> models = new List<DummyObj>()
{
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 1, ChildKey = 1, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 00:00:00"), Name = "Single item - not grouped" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 2, ChildKey = 2, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 01:00:00"), Name = "Should be grouped with line below" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 2, ChildKey = 3, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 02:00:00"), Name = "Grouped with above" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 2, ChildKey = 4, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 04:00:00"), Name = "Separate item as greater than 2 hours" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 2, ChildKey = 5, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 05:00:00"), Name = "Grouped with above" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 3, ChildKey = 6, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 05:00:00"), Name = "Single item - not grouped" }
};

private class DummyObj
{
    public int ParentKey { set; get; }
    public int ChildKey { set; get; }
    public DateTime TheDate { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

The resulting grouping should be (child keys):

```
{[1]}, {[2,3]}, {[4,5]}, {[6]}
```

I could group by parent key first then loop through comparing the individual items within the groups but hoping for a more elegant solution.

As always, thank you very much.

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        var list = GetListFromDb(); //returns List<DummyObj>;
        var sortedList = new List<DummyObj>();
        foreach(var g in list.GroupBy(x => x.ParentKey))
        {
            if(g.Count() < 2)
            {
                sortedList.Add(g.First());
            }
            else
            {
                var datesInGroup = g.Select(x => x.TheDate);
                var hoursDiff = (datesInGroup.Max() - datesInGroup.Min()).TotalHours;
                if(hoursDiff <= 2)
                {
                    string combinedName = string.Join("; ", g.Select(x => x.Name));
                    g.First().Name = combinedName;
                    sortedList.Add(g.First());
                }
                else
                {
                    //now it's the mess
                    DateTime earliest = g.Select(x => x.TheDate).Min();
                    var subGroup = new List<DummyObj>();
                    foreach(var line in g)
                    {
                        if((line.TheDate - earliest).TotalHours > 2)
                        {   
                            //add the current subgroup entry to the sorted group
                            subGroup.First().Name = string.Join("; ", subGroup.Select(x => x.Name));
                            sortedList.Add(subGroup.First());
                            //new group needed and new earliest date to start the group
                            sortedList = new List<DummyObj>();
                            sortedList.Add(line);
                            earliest = line.TheDate;                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            subGroup.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                    //add final sub group, i.e. when there's none that are over 2 hours apart or the last sub group
                    if(subGroup.Count > 1)
                    {
                        subGroup.First().Name = string.Join("; ", subGroup.Select(x => x.Name));
                        sortedList.Add(subGroup.First());
                    }
                    else if(subGroup.Count == 1)
                    {
                        sortedList.Add(subGroup.First());
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share your attempted code ?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Finding similar records in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852681/finding-similar-records-in-linq)

Comment: There are many similar question, look for "group by" in combination with "time buckets" or "time intervals". One gotcha: you can't group by "separated by 2 hours". If A and B are separated by 1.5h and B and C also, A and C are separated by 3h. You can only group into predefined 2-hour time intervals.

Comment: @GertArnold - "You can only group into predefined 2-hour time intervals" - not true.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sure it is, just create items that are all 1 hour apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
List<DummyObj> models = new List<DummyObj>()
{
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 1, ChildKey = 1, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 00:00:00"), Name = "Single item - not grouped" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 2, ChildKey = 2, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 01:00:00"), Name = "Should be grouped with line below" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 2, ChildKey = 3, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 02:00:00"), Name = "Grouped with above" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 2, ChildKey = 4, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 04:00:00"), Name = "Separate item as greater than 2 hours" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 2, ChildKey = 5, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 05:00:00"), Name = "Grouped with above" },
    new DummyObj { ParentKey = 3, ChildKey = 6, TheDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2020 05:00:00"), Name = "Single item - not grouped" }
};

List<List<DummyObj>> groups =
    models
        .GroupBy(x => x.ParentKey)
        .Select(xs => xs.OrderBy(x => x.TheDate).ToList())
        .SelectMany(xs => xs.Skip(1).Aggregate(new[] { xs.Take(1).ToList() }.ToList(), (a, x) =>
        {
            if (x.TheDate.Subtract(a.Last().Last().TheDate).TotalHours < 2.0)
            {
                a.Last().Add(x);
            }
            else
            {
                a.Add(new [] { x }.ToList());
            }
            return a;
        }))
        .ToList();

string output =
    String.Join(", ",
        groups.Select(x =>
            $"{{[{String.Join(",", x.Select(y => $"{y.ChildKey}"))}]}}"));
```

That gives me:

```
{[1]}, {[2,3]}, {[4,5]}, {[6]}
```

[image: groups]

Comment: This is not correct. Just give all items the same parent and set them 1h apart. They all end up in 1 group.

Comment: @GertArnold - Please explain more clearly. The output matches exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Maybe OP should tell more clearly what they want. If they just want to make divisions in any list of ordered DateTimes where they are 2h apart, then this code is OK, but it seems they want to group in 2h periods, seeing their code, where items within one group are not supposed to be > 2h later than `earliest`.

Comment: @Enigmativity is correct - I am looking for grouping as above. If an item is greater than 2 hours from the previous 'earliest date' then it should start a new grouping.

Comment: As for the issue of 1 hour apart each time, e.g. [t0, t1, t2] [t3, t4] [t6, t7, t8] so on and so forth.